# sort the array of fields in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a scenario where i have ratings and rounds in array named `ratings`
I need to sort the ratings in descending order based on rounds(1,2,3,4).
I am using express js and mongoose driver for queries

query:

```
   **//Get top ratings based on round
exports.topRating = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query);
    Profiles.aggregate([{
            $match: {
                "hiringManager": req.query.hiringManager,
                "ratings.round":parseInt(req.query.round)
            }
        },{ $sort : { "ratings.rating" : -1 } }],
        function(err, profiles) {
            if (err) {
                return handleError(res, err);
            }
            console.log(profiles);
            return res.status(200).json(fnStruncturedData(profiles));

        });
};
```

Schema :

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),

        Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var ProfilesSchema = new Schema({
    name:String,
    ratings: [{
            round: Number,
            rating: Number,
            feedback: String,
            interviewer: String,
            roundStatus: String
        }]
    })
```

suppose i have data stored in db as below

```
[{
name:"a",
ratings:[{
                round: 1,
                rating: 3,
                feedback: "something",
                interviewer: "abc",
                roundStatus: "selected"
            },

{
                round: 2,
                rating: 5,
                feedback: "something",
                interviewer: "abc",
                roundStatus: "selected"
            },
{
                round: 3,
                rating: 4,
                feedback: "something",
                interviewer: "abc",
                roundStatus: "selected"
            },{
                round: 4,
                rating: 1,
                feedback: "something",
                interviewer: "abc",
                roundStatus: "selected"
            }]
},
{
name:"b",
ratings:[{
                round: 1,
                rating: 5,
                feedback: "something",
                interviewer: "abc",
                roundStatus: "selected"
            },

{
                round: 2,
                rating: 4,
                feedback: "something",
                interviewer: "abc",
                roundStatus: "selected"
            },
{
                round: 3,
                rating: 3,
                feedback: "something",
                interviewer: "abc",
                roundStatus: "selected"
            },{
                round: 4,
                rating: 2,
                feedback: "something",
                interviewer: "abc",
                roundStatus: "selected"
            }]
}]
```

i have  adrop down at client side where a user select the rounds and accordingly top ratings will appear. 
for say round one:
the data is sorted and according to the query i am getting `name:b`data first in an array 
for second round :
I should get `name:a` first in an  array but it is again showing `name:b` data first
here i could sort round 1 ratings perfectly while round (2,3,4) is showing no change 
I dont understand whats wrong in query 
please help

Comment: Add sample data and what you get and what is expected

Comment: Still not so clear. Add expected and current result as json.

Comment: actually it is showing overall top ratings rather than round wise

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the data from the rounds you are not interested in is still included, and is impacting your sort stage.

If the data from those other rounds does not need to be returned, a simple solution is to $unwind ratings first, which will then exclude all the non matching rounds in your $match stage.

For example, this should work:

```
[
{
    $unwind: "$ratings"
},
{
    $match: {
        "hiringManager": req.query.hiringManager,
        "ratings.round":parseInt(req.query.round)
    }
},
{
    $sort: { 
        "ratings.rating" : -1 
    } 
}
]
```